# packet loss between two specific VMs

Tags: networking, ping, local-area-network, hadoop, packetloss

I am experiencing some high-percentage packet loss (more than 70%) between two specific VMs in a local network, in a remote cluster (I have no physical access to it).

One machine is used as a hadoop master and the other as a hadoop slave. 
The strange thing is that when I ping any other machine from/to any of these two machines, I get no packet loss. Network configurations for all the slave nodes are identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is fixed. Here are the two things I did:

1. I changed the `etc/network/interfaces` file (in Ubuntu) and added my local network with a static IP for my machine, like this:

> ```
> auto eth1
> iface eth1 inet static
> address 192.168.0.18
> netmask 255.255.255.0
> gateway 192.168.0.1`
> ```

2. The new IP of my VM (`192.168.0.18`) is different than the previous one (`192.168.0.2`).

Any comments on how did that solve my problem?

Comment: Is there another machine on the subnet that uses the previous IP  (192.168.0.2) ?

Comment: @nkms this could be the case, since the ips are given automatically when i create a new VM and add it to the subnet. I will check it, but I guess you are right. After deleting and adding VMs, this could cause a problem...

Answer (score -1):

My first idea would be to check netmasks on VMs and router in between. If you need more help I would need more infos on VM technology, network topology and OS specifics...

Comment: 1. The OP states that these VM's are in a local network, which is remote to the OP. The VM's are not remote to each other so this probably has nothing to do with routing. 2. Using an incorrect subnet mask on one of the VM's would result in 100% packet loss as no communication could occur between the VM's.

Comment: @marc99 the netmasks of all VMs are 255.255.255.0
 All nodes run Ubuntu 12.04 LTS servers. I don't know about the topology, or VM technology.

Comment: @joeqwerty do you suspect something else is wrong? I can check that, even if it is not the correct answer. No worries :)

Comment: Netmasks, for packet loss (with some connectivity)?  Really?